# Should I unit test $routeProvider when() settings to prevent app from breaking at run time?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

```
$routeProvider.when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'app/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController as vm'
});
```

If I change `vm` to (say) `avm`, it passes unit tests, runs but breaks the view on run time.

[image]

This can be caught by functional tests, but that's too slow. Any thought about this situation is welcome.

If I can, **how would I do that?**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good idea and isn't too hard to add a simple test...

```
describe('Testing route configuration', function() {
  var $routeProvider;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('ngRoute', function(_$routeProvider_) {
      $routeProvider = _$routeProvider_;
      spyOn(routeProvider, 'when');
    }, 'your.module.name');
    inject(); // this "runs" the modules
  });

  it('register the correct route config', function() {
    expect($routeProvider.when).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'app/login.html',
      controller: 'LoginController as vm'
    });
  });
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/GIpPkSPaBxm0N5wN29Hx?p=preview